# use a Variable as a key on JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

my json is like this : 
`

```
{
    "isfahan": [

    {  
        "id"   : "1",
        "city" : "ahar",                
        "top"  : "35%",
        "left" : "54%"

    },
    {  
        "id"   : "2",
        "city" : "marand",              
        "top"  : "35%",
        "left" : "54%"

    },
    {  
        "id"   : "3",
        "city" : "miane",               
        "top"  : "35%",
        "left" : "54%"

    }

],

"azerbaijan": [

    {  
        "id"   : "3",
        "city" : "miane",               
        "top"  : "35%",
        "left" : "54%"

    },
    {  
        "id"   : "3",
        "city" : "miane",               
        "top"  : "35%",
        "left" : "54%"

    }
],

"ardabil": [

    {  
        "id"   : "3",
        "city" : "miane",               
        "top"  : "35%",
        "left" : "54%"

    },
    {  
        "id"   : "3",
        "city" : "miane",               
        "top"  : "35%",
        "left" : "54%"

    },
    {  
        "id"   : "3",
        "city" : "miane",               
        "top"  : "35%",
        "left" : "54%"

    },
    {  
        "id"   : "3",
        "city" : "miane",               
        "top"  : "35%",
        "left" : "54%"

    }
]
      }
```

and to get JSON object i'm going to use such a this :

```
                var pulse_state = $('#state_var').html();

                $.getJSON("data/pulse.json").done(function(data){

                        localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));
                        $.each(data.isfahan, function(index, value){

                            $(".cd-points-container").append(
                               "<li class='cd-single-point' style='top:"+value.top+"; left:"+value.left+";'><a class='cd-img-replace' href='#0'>اطلاعات بیشتر</a><div class='cd-more-info cd-left'><h2>"+ value.city + "</h2><p>"+ value.sepah_text +"</p><a href='#0' class='cd-close-info cd-img-replace'>Close</a></div></li><!-- .cd-single-point -->"

                            );

                        });
                        //end each function
```

as you see if i use `data.isfahan` to get array , everything is ok but if i change `data.isfahan` to `data.pulse_state' , it goes wrong !!!!!

i mean i want to use a variable named `data.pulse_state` and then get JSON object,

could you help me out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
data[pulse_state]
```

instead of `data.pulse_state`.